# How to produce a unique key from duplicate map values

Tags: java, groovy

I have a JSON which contains a list of maps:

```
{
"aprLimits": [{
    "orgId": "Company 1",
    "rangeStart": "54936",
    "rangeEnd": "54936",
    "amountLimit": 100000
}, {
    "orgId": "Company 1",
    "rangeStart": "59434",
    "rangeEnd": "59434",
    "amountLimit": 0.01
}, {
    "orgId": "Company 1",
    "rangeStart": "54345",
    "rangeEnd": "54345",
    "amountLimit": 0
}, {
    "orgId": "Company 1",
    "rangeStart": "54345",
    "rangeEnd": "54345",
    "amountLimit": 250000
}, {
    "orgId": "Company 2",
    "rangeStart": "043",
    "rangeEnd": "043",
    "amountLimit": 0.01
}, {
    "orgId": "Company 2",
    "rangeStart": "042",
    "rangeEnd": "042",
    "amountLimit": 1000
}, {
    "orgId": "Company 2",
    "rangeStart": "032",
    "rangeEnd": "032",
    "amountLimit": 0
}]}
```

My goal is to collect data corresponding to the unique orgId by converting it to a key and assigning the rest of the values to it so the end result looks like this:

```
["Company 1": [[54936, 54936, 100000], [59434, 59434, 0.01], [54345, 54345, 0], [54345, 54345, 250000]], "Company 2": [[043, 043, 0.01], [042, 042, 1000], [032, 032, 0]]]
```

I've got as far as getting unique orgId's and collecting data into lists but I have trouble figuring out how to associate the unique key to the lists

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(json)
def list = []
def orgIds = parsedJson.aprLimits.orgId.unique()

parsedJson.aprLimits.each {
if (orgIds.contains(it.orgId)) {
    data = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(it.rangeStart, it.rangeEnd, it.amountLimit))
    list.add(data)
}}
```

Comment: Create a result map instead of list `def map=[:]` and then put pairs - orgid and new array into this map `map.put(it.orgId, data)`

Comment: Since there are duplicate values of orgId, only the last results of the loop will end up in the map, e.g. [Company 1:[54345, 54345, 250000], Company 2:[032, 032, 0]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good start here would be `groupBy` and then shape the data you want it.  Shorter is a *reduce* with a map with default values.  E.g.

```
parsedJson.aprLimits.inject(
    [:].withDefault{[]} // if a key is missing, add it and make the value an empty vector
){ r, v -> 
    r[v.orgId] << [v.rangeStart, v.rangeEnd, v.amountLimit]
    r
}
```